# Using Grand Stream call center API to Call a phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I'm using below code to call a phone number in my Asp.Net web forms app by using Grand Stream UCM6301 call center:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();                
var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
byte[] response;
string responseString;
dynamic data;

parameters.Add("action", "dialOutbound");
parameters.Add("outbound", phoneNumber);
parameters.Add("caller", internalNumber);
parameters.Add("cookie", Globals.Instance.CallCenterCookie);

response = wc.UploadValues(Constants.URLs.CALL_CENTER_URL, parameters);
responseString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
data = JObject.Parse(responseString);
```

Everything is ok and code is working as expected when I'm running on local machine, but when I publish the app to IIS the code does nothing although API call is successful.

Comment: You are making a HTTP request and getting a HTTP response.  A good response will return a 200 ok and a bad response will return a 400/500 error.  I suspect you are getting an error in the response and when you get an error there is no body (response string).  Or the parameters are different when you are executing on the remote machine and the query is returning no results.

Comment: I'm getting "200 ok" response when calling API on IIS but nothing happens

Comment: The connection is completing and authentication is good.  You are not getting any data from the query.  Most likely there is no data that matches the parameters.  You are performing a query into a database on the IIS.  The query is returning no data.  So you get a 200 OK, but no data is returned in the body of the response.  Try a simple query that returns all the phone number and see if you get data.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed request process, which can help you analyze and solve problems.